# Filtering input text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, html-input

I want to filter and lock a input text. For example, in some input, a user can only type Persian/Farsi characters but not English, or when user can type in English but not Persian. Means some input only accepts Persian/Farsi characters and others only accept English.

Also i foundthis http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input. If know any regular experssion for persian characters can help me
or how can change the keyboard mode.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the list of [Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Arabic) it seems you need to check symbols in the unicode range `U+0600-U+06FF`.

So if you want to prevent the insertion of every other unicode symbol you could simply check your input value against `/^[\u0600-\u06FF]+$/g` regular expression. Also note that there're many unicode ranges you may want to allow. From the page of [Arabic charset in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_characters_in_Unicode), beside Arabic (0600—06FF, 225 characters) you have

- Arabic Supplement (0750—077F, 48 characters)
- Arabic Extended-A (08A0—08FF, 39 characters)
- Arabic Presentation Forms-A (FB50—FDFF, 608 characters)
- Arabic Presentation Forms-B (FE70—FEFF, 140 characters)
- Rumi Numeral Symbols (10E60—10E7F, 31 characters)
- Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols (1EE00—1EEFF, 143 characters)

in that case add as many ranges as you need in the expression:
e.g. `/^[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\077F\u0...]+$/g`

So, using the snippet you mentioned you should write

```
$('#text_input').filter_input({regex:'[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\077F\u0...]'});
```

Hope this helps. السلام عليكم